# I get a weird sysmalloc: Assertion error when using a trie

Tags: c, dictionary, malloc, trie

I have an assignment for checking if some input words are from a dictionary and print and count the ones that are not. Initially the dictionary was an array and I had to change it to a trie to make it faster (the code that is between /* */ is the changed code). After trying to compile it I get this weird

[image]

I have no idea what to do now. The files and code that I used are the following:
dictionary.h:

```
// declares a dictionary

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// maximum length for a word
#define LENGTH 45
//Nr of possible children=size of the alphabet
#define N 26

//a trie as dictionary
typedef struct dict
{
    bool is_word;
    struct dict *children[N];
} dict;


// a dictionary is an array
/* typedef struct dict {
  int numWords;
  int maxWords;
  char **words;
} dict; 
*/



dict *newEmptyDict();
void addWord(char word[LENGTH + 1], dict *d);
bool check(const char *word, dict *d);
void freeDict(dict *n);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
```

dictionary.c:

```
// implements a dictionary

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"
#define CHAR_TO_INDEX(c) ((int)c - (int)'a')

/* dict *newEmptyDict() {
  dict *d = malloc(sizeof(dict));
  if (d == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  d->numWords = 0;
  d->maxWords = 1;
  d->words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * d->maxWords);
  return d;
}
*/

//create an empty trie dictionary
dict *newEmptyDict() {
    dict *pN = NULL;
    pN=(dict*)malloc(sizeof(dict));
    if (pN){
        int i;
        pN->is_word=false;
        for (i=0;i<=N;i++)
            pN->children[i]=NULL;

    }
    return pN;
}

// add word to the dictionary if it is is not already known
/* void addWord(char word[LENGTH + 1], dict *d) {
  if (!check(word, d)) {
    // if we need more space before adding the word, double the size
    if (d->numWords == d->maxWords) {
      d->words = realloc(d->words,(sizeof(char*)) * (d->maxWords * 2));
      if (d->words == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory.\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
      d->maxWords = d->maxWords * 2;
    }
    // now we actually add the word
    d->words[d->numWords] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (LENGTH + 1));
    strcpy(d->words[d->numWords],word);
    d->numWords++;
  }
} */

void addWord(char word[LENGTH + 1], dict *d) {
    int level;
    int len=strlen(word);
    int index;
    dict *pC = d;
    for (level=0;level<len;level++){
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(word[level]);
        if(!pC->children[index])
            pC->children[index] = newEmptyDict();
        pC=pC->children[index];
    }
    pC->is_word = true;

}

// check whether word is in dictionary
/* bool check(const char *word, dict *d) {
  for (int i = 0; i < d->numWords; i++) {
    if (strcmp(d->words[i],word) == 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
} */

bool check(const char *word, dict *d) {
    int level; 
    int len=strlen(word); 
    int index;
    dict *pC = d;
    for (level=0;level<len;level++){
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(word[level]); 
        if (!pC->children[index]) 
            return false; 
        pC=pC->children[index]; 
    } 

    return (pC!=NULL && pC->is_word); 
} 


/* void freeDict(dict *d) {
  for (int i = 0; i < d->numWords; i++) {
    free(d->words[i]);
  }
  free(d->words);
  free(d);
}
*/
void freeDict(dict *d) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=N;i++)
        if (d->children[i]) freeDict(d->children[i]);
    free (d);
}
```

speller.c:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// remove non-alphabetic characters and convert to lower case
void trimWord(char *word) {
  int k = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < (int) strlen(word); i++) {
    if (isalpha(word[i])) {
      word[k] = tolower(word[i]);
      k++;
    }
  }
  word[k] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char word[LENGTH + 1] = "";

  // step 1: read in the dictionary
  dict *dictionary = newEmptyDict();
  while (scanf("%45s",word) && word[0] != '!') {
    trimWord(word);
    addWord(word,dictionary);
    memset(word,0,strlen(word));
  }

  // step 2: read in text
  int counter = 0; // number of unknown words

  // BUG: This loop is wrong. It will read "one,twwo" as one word "onetwwo".
  /* while (scanf("%45s", word) != EOF) {
    trimWord(word);
    if (!check(word,dictionary)) {
      counter++;
      printf("%s\n",word);
    }
  }
  */
  int index = 0; int wcheck=0; //wcheck is for knowing if a word has begun so no unnecesary \n's are printed
  int c = EOF;
  while ((c = getchar()) && c != EOF) {
    if (isalpha(c)){
        word[index]=c;
        index++;
        wcheck=1;
    }else if (wcheck){
        trimWord(word);
        if(!check(word,dictionary)){
            counter++;
            printf("%s\n", word);
        }
        memset(word,0,strlen(word));
        index=0;
        wcheck=0;
    }
  } 
  // TODO: Replace the above while loop with a correct solution.
  // Hints:
  // - you should read one character at a time, using getchar()
  // - alphabetical characters should be appended to the current word
  // - any other symbol should terminate the word
  // this code might be useful:
  /*
  int index = 0;
  int c = EOF;
  while ((c = getchar()) && c != EOF) {
    // ...
  }
  */

  // step 3: print number of unknown words
  printf("%d\n", counter);

  freeDict(dictionary);
  return 0;
}
```

Could you help please? I believe it has something to do with allocation but I'm still stuck. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't show images of text, copy-paste the text *as text* into the question instead. Also please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem that's a *crash*. You should run your program in a *debugger* to catch the crash when it happens. The debugger will then let you examine the function call stack so you can see where in your code it happens. If you walk up the call-stack to your code, you can also examine variables and their values to make sure everything seems alright.

Comment: A *big* problem though: `for (i=0;i<=N;i++) pN->children[i]=NULL;` This loop *will* go out of bounds of the array `children`. Remember that for an array of `N` elements, the indexes are `0` to `N - 1` (inclusive). Going out of bounds of arrays leads to *undefined behavior*, and could possibly cause your crash.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do not know how to use a debugger yet, but your advice solved it :D. Thank you soooo much! Also, I will take the time to read it. Thanks again!